# Prove that there exists a proper subgroup $H$ in a non-abelian group $G$ such that the center of $G$ is a proper subset of $H$

Tags: group-theory

Attempt: since the center of any abelian group is the group itself we need to show by contrapositive that if the sequence $Z(G)\subset H\leq G $ (where $Z(G)\neq H\neq G$) fails to hold then $G$ must be abelian. Though I'm not sure how to express the the hypothesis "such $H$ doesn't exist" algebraically.

Comment: If you're just asking about the formal language, the negation would be that every subgroup $H$ of $G$ is either not proper ($H=G$) or does not properly contain the center ($H=Z(G)$ or $Z(G) \nsubseteq H$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of lazy, but you could prove it directly if you know that the centralizer of a group element is always a subgroup. Since $G$ is non-abelian, it has some element $g$ such that $g$ does not commute with some other element, say $h$. Then $C(g)$, the centralizer of $g$, meaning the group of elements that commute with $g$, does not contain $h$ so it is a proper subgroup of $G$, and it contains the center.

Then how do we know that $C(g)$ *properly* contains $Z(G)$? Simple! $g$ is not in the center, since it does not commute with $h$, but it is in $C(g)$, since it commutes with itself.

Answer (score 3):

In a nonabelian group $G$, we know that $G/Z(G)$ is not cyclic. In particular, $G/Z(G)$ has a proper nontrivial cyclic subgroup: just take any element different from the identity. Such a subgroup can be seen as $H/Z(G)$ for a unique subgroup $H$ of $G$ containing $Z(G)$.